# How to add downloaded image to ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-image

I am trying to add downloaded images to a `ListView`. I start out by getting the names of the image files from my server and then I do an `AsyncTask` of building the bitmaps and storing them in a `Bitmap[]` array. Then I use a `HashMap` to add the data using the `SimpleAdapter` shown below. I want to know how to add the bitmap images to the list view.

Right now I am getting an error on the line where I attempt to put the item photo into the hash map. How do I resolve that? Do I have to move them to the `drawable` resources directory? I am totally new to this and will appreciate any help in getting downloaded images into a list view. Here is how I prepare the data. All of this is taking place in the `onPostExecute()` method of my async task in which OI perform another async task to get the image files.

```
new AccessImages().execute("http://10.0.2.2:8000/herbivorenew/" + viewdata[2]);

List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

for (int i=0;i< count; i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put("item_header", viewtext[i]);
    // built from an asynctask from the server
    hm.put("item_photo", (Bitmap)(itemphoto[i]) );
    hm.put("carrots", Integer.toString(carrotimage[i]) );

    aList.add(hm);
}

// Keys used in Hashmap
String[] from = {"item_header", "item_photo", "carrots"};

// Ids of views in listview_layout
int[] to = {R.id.item_header, R.id.item_photo, R.id.item_carrot};

// Instantiating an adapter to store each items
// R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), 
aList, R.layout.itemlist, from, to);

// Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
ListView item_list = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listitems);
item_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is where I get the downloaded images:

```
private class AccessImages extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urladds){
        return downloadImage(urladds[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) {
        itemphoto[itemcount] = bmp;
        itemcount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope it help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Answer (score 0):

> if you do like this way it takes too much of time.
>     instead of that use lazy loading concept.
>     [by following this link you can resolve this issue](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)